# Selenium allow redirect

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Selenium doesn't load the page if it gets redirected before the page loads. The error is:

> Message: unknown error: net::ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED

Here is a simple selenium code example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome() 
browser.get('http://loginrequired.com/')
```

Selenium wouldn't load the page, because the website immideately redirects us to the other page.

How do I let Selenium to ignore the redirection and follow all next steps on the redirected page? This website is takes for the example purpose, so the answer would not be simply to try to get to the redirected page immideatly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the webdriver.ChromeOptions() class and set the --disable-web-security and --disable-extensions arguments. This can disable web security and extensions in the browser instance used by Selenium.

By disabling web security and extensions, you allow Selenium to bypass the error related to SOCKS connection failure and proceed with the redirection.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Initialize Chrome driver with the options
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```